# Display data in text field on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, sensormanager

How can I display the data obtained by the accelerometer in the `EditText` text box?
It works just using `TextView`

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float x,y,z;
    x=event.values[0];
    y=event.values[1];
    z=event.values[2];
    axex =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    axex.setText(X+x+ms^2);
    axey=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    axey.setText(Y+y+ms^2);
    axez=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    axez.setText(Z+z+ms^2);
}
```

Comment: If that's a programming question then a program is missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_text);
text.setText("Display this text");
```

Comment: as Snicolas wrote, your question is not a real question. You need to give some details, errors, code samples to get an answer.

Comment: I want to display the results of the accelerometer in the text field but it dosn't work, here's a piece of code:

Comment: I want to display the results of the accelerometer in the text field but it dosn't work, here's a piece of code:                         public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   
  float x,y,z;
  x=event.values[0];
  y=event.values[1];
  z=event.values[2];
     axex =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       axex.setText(X+x+ms^2);
     axey=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
             axey.setText(Y+y+ms^2);
        axez=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                axez.setText(Z+z+ms^2);
  
  
 }
}

Comment: I have not received any errors but the application does not work in the emulator

Comment: sensors not supported on emulators which I know And your question is setting data to editText which is not related to neither emulator nor sensor usage. you need to be more clear on your questions.

Comment: Check this SensorSimulator: http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

Comment: No in this case the accelerometer data will give fixed values ​​for x, y, z because it does not detect any movement

Comment: mybe we can't use a texte filed to save the result of  the accelerometer coz the information change too fast.So it work when i use TexteView:) 
then i will frgot about it...here My Application with the emulator and when i use my phone
the data varies by moving it![enter image description here][1]  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx2Xz.png

Answer (score 0):

```
axex.setText(Float.toString(X+x+ms^2));
```

try that.